# To convert a string into Hexadecimal value vb

Tags: string, vb.net

I have a textbox that captures strings like `0XA5, 0X2E, 0X34` and so on.

I want to convert it into a hexadecimal value like `&HA5` etc and send it to a serial port (which accepts only hexadecimal numbers in the form of '&H__') using VB.

I have looked online and I am very confused. Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: To convert the data to numbers, you can split it on ",", trim the resulting array elements, and use the [Convert.ToInt32 Method (String, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614(v=vs.110).aspx): *If fromBase is 16, you can prefix the number specified by the value parameter with "0x" or "0X".*

Comment: @AndrewMorton The serial port accepts input in the form of hexadecimal numbers and not integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: @Rahul The number base makes no difference to the value of the number - the only difference is how it is displayed. You might find Convert.ToByte more convenient.

Comment: This is confusing. If the data is sent by number then it shouldn't care about the format. Seems like you need to send the data as string, in that case just replace 0X to &H.

Comment: Could perhaps show us how you send values _without_ a text box? `The serial port accepts input in the form of hexadecimal numbers and not integers` is _**extremely vague**_ as we don't know _in what form_ it accepts the data. Hexadecimal numbers are just another way of representing normal integers in Visual Basic.

Comment: The tool to which the data is being sent, accepts the data in the form "&H__". That is why I cannot pass integers.

Comment: So in other words you just need to send an ordinary string? Then djv's answer does what you require.

Comment: Yes, But there are some calculation related to the hex values, which ill have to carry out.So, I cannot simply use replace.

Comment: @Rahul what calculation? you didn't specify that in your question. You only said you need to send the data from the textbox.

Comment: Convert to Integer (A Friend's answer) -> Perform calculations with Integer -> Convert Integer to HEX string -> Replace prefix (djv's answer) -> Send data -> Done.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yep that's my plan however I don't know whose answer to accept now :S

Comment: I forgot to upvote them myself. :D

Comment: I think in this case, maybe use a combination of each answer and a little of your own magic to answer the question yourself! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the serial port accepts "only hexadecimal numbers in the form of '&H__'", it would be fairly simple to use String.Replace

```
Dim input = "0XA5" ' simulate TextBox input
Dim output = Input.Replace("0X", "&H")
```

and send `output` to the serial port.

To check the resulting value,

```
Console.WriteLine("Input: {0}, Output {1}", input, output)
```

yields

> Input: 0XA5, Output &HA5

Answer (score 1):

Converts the `TextBox` value to an integer of base 16 (hex)

```
Dim hexValueAsInteger = Convert.ToInt32(YourTxtBox.Text, 16)
```

Comment: Hey, I want to send the textbox value as a hexadecimal value, not an integer. So, 0XA5 would be &HA5. Is there any function for this? I am also performing some operations on decimals and then converting them into hexadecimal. So, 165 would be &HA5(just an example).

Comment: You want to be using `Byte`s then

Comment: Could you tell me how?

Comment: I've marked as potential duplicate. If you convert the answer to VB, all you'll need to do is trim the leading "0x"

Comment: @AFriend If you check the documentation I linked to, you will discover that is not necessary.

Comment: In the dupe target it is. But the documentation you linked is essentially the content of my answer, yes.